# Running EF database migrations in shared hosting environment

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a site hosted on shared hosting, and when trying to run 'update-database' I get this error:

> This operation requires a connection to the 'master' database. Unable
>   to create a connection to the 'master' database because the original
>   database connection has been opened and credentials have been removed
>   from the connection string. Supply an unopened connection.

Obviously provider won't give me an access to master. Am I out of luck?

Comment: Why is your migration trying to access the master database?  It should only try to do things in your application's database(s).  Do you have a custom migration that touches master?

Comment: No. But EF runs this command - "select cast(serverproperty('EngineEdition') as int)" before it starts updates, which I suppose requires an access to master db.

Comment: I don't expect that requires access to `master`, but I believe permission to access serverproperties can be controlled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`update-database` does indeed need access to the 'master' database in order to add new databases.  Entity Framework assumes the database to not exist by default, and will run `Create Database`.  If your host provider is only giving you access to a shared instance instead of your own instance on a shared server, then you probably can't create new Databases without their help.

If you use the command `Update-Database -Script -SourceMigration: $InitialDatabase`, it will generate a `.sql` script which can be run against the database, either by your hosting provider or through whatever portal they provide you.

Comment: What tables are added to the master database?

Comment: Perfect. Not ideal, that is, but its a workable solution. Thanks!

Comment: updated to be more clear, it's actually that Entity Framework is trying to add the new Database to the 'master' table

Comment: That makes no sense to me.  I doubt that Update-Database -Script will script anything that references master.

Comment: it is also possible that after you create the database with the correct name, that the rest of the update-database commands will work without issue.

Comment: Hm, checked sql profiler, and it didn't attempt to create a db. It would be dumb to try creating db without checking if it exists first.. which again probably requires access to master.

Comment: The db already existed, it was purely alter table stuff. Didn't fly.

Comment: I didn't suggest that it wasn't odd that it required 'master' for it's internal process, but the Script itself should be less invasive.